# Query string URL filling form text field even though its name is different

Tags: html, forms, get

This is my form HTML.  A query string in url is in this format. `http://myurl.com/?source=test`

```
<form method='get' action='/some-url'>
 <input type='text' name='address'>
<button type='submit' />GO</button>
```

Now, when I access the url in the above format, it is filling the form text field with that query string value 'test'. But, my text field name attribute is 'address'.

I don't want to fill the text field with the value from the url. Is there any approach to resolve this issue?

```
<html>
    <form id="bh-test" method="get" action="test.php">
        <input type="text" name="address" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: use ajax to send data without form

Comment: No, with different name attribute, it should not fill that value in that text field. But why its updating the value?

Comment: provide some more details about your problem

Comment: show more of your code

Comment: added code in the description. Please see it.